# How to use virtual serial port without root privileges?

Tags: udev, serial-port, kubuntu, socat

Background: I want to use 
[this Wifi-to-Serial adapter](http://www.skysafariastronomy.com/skyfi-3-professional-astronomy-telescope-control.html)
to control a telescope via
[Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/)
running on Kubuntu 16.04 (64 Bit).

I'd created a virtual com port using `socat` with this command line:

```
$ sudo socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw tcp:10.0.0.1:4030
```

and I see the new device here:

```
$ ls -l /dev/virtualcom0 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2017-07-03 09:05 virtualcom0 -> /dev/pts/6
$ ls -l /dev/pts/6
crw--w---- 1 root tty 136, 6 2017-07-03 09:05 /dev/pts/6
```

Trying to use `/dev/virtualcom0` e.g. with `picocomm` works as long as I run `picosomm` with root privileges. But when I try to use the port with standard user privileges, I got an error:

```
$ picocom /dev/virtualcom0 --baud 9600 --imap lfcrlf
FATAL: cannot open /dev/virtualcom0: Permission denied
```

Any idea how to make the virtual com port accessable with standard user rights, maybe by defining a special udev rule for this?

#### Edit #1

Following the preferred approach of dirkt's answer, I'm now using:

```
$ socat pty,link=/tmp/virtualcom0,raw tcp:10.0.0.1:4030
```

Note, that this also works fine on macOS (after installed socat via homebrew).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write to a Serial Port Without Root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/read-write-to-a-serial-port-without-root)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't fully understand why you need a virtual serial port at all. What happens if you just `telnet 10.0.0.1 4030`?

Next thing is to run `socat` without `sudo` as normal user and pick a path that's accessible, e.g. `/tmp/vcom0` (or whatever).

If that doesn't work for some reason, and you obvious can do `sudo`, try changing owner

```
sudo chown your_username /dev/virtualcom0
```

or permissions

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/virtualcom0
```

**Edit**

Don't try to make `udev` rules for a particular pseudo tty. First, you don't know in advance which pseudo tty it is, second, pseudo tty's are used all over the place, and other programs will fail if they happen to create this pseudo tty for another user.

The cleanest solution is to use variant (1) (`/tmp/vcom0`).

If you insist on the other variants, make a short script that contains both the `socat` and the `chmod`/`chown`, and execute that script with `sudo`. You can follow symbol links with `readlink`, if necessary.

Another alternative is to write a short script that calls both `socat` as normal user, and `stellarium` with the link it made, and kills `socat` when it's done. Use that script to start `stellarium`.

Comment: I need a virtual serial port for accessing it via Stellarium.

Comment: Great, all three solutions are working. For the `chown` and `chmod` approach it's finally that they change `/dev/pts/6` permissions from `crw--w---- root tty` to e.g.  `crw--w---- joe joe` or `crw--w-rw- root tty` or `crw-rw---- root dialout`.

Comment: Did you have an idea how to apply `chmod` / `chown` automatically by using e.g. an udev-rule? I'd tried `SUBSYSTEM=="pty", MODE="0666"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="pts", MODE="0666"` both without success (permissions of `/dev/pts/6` stay at `crw--w---- root tty`).

Answer (score 8):

I found an answer after pouring through the man page for socat.

You can add mode and group to the attributes of your pty by adding a few more expressions to your command line. To follow your example, but with your new serial port owned by the dialout group and with read/write access for that group, do this:

```
$ sudo socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw,group-late=dialout,mode=660 tcp:10.0.0.1:4030
```